# Difference between cherry-pick commit methods in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio

To cherry-pick commits in Visual Studio I usually right-click the origin branch, click in "View History" and cherry-pick the commits I want to merge to the currently checked out branch.
What's the difference when you just right-click the origin branch and click in "Cherry-pick"?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cherry-picking deals with commits, and disregards any branch consideration. Any commit can be cherry-picked if the ref is known somewhere in the repo tree.

**The two features you're comparing here are just presentation alternatives**. In terms of interface building, VisualStudio designers chose to allow cherry-picking in different ways, but under the hood a cherry-pick is a cherry-pick.

Only things that matter (when you cherry-pick) are

1. the position of `HEAD` (which will be the new commit's parent)
2. the commit `cherry-pick` points to.

---

More specifically, for the upper feature you're highlighting ("Cherry-pick"), it doesn't show the hash of the commit you'll cherry-pick, but **it's implied by design to be the tip commit** (the last) of the branch you just right-clicked and displayed the contextual actions.

(As eftshift0 duly [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55482275/difference-between-cherry-pick-commit-methods-in-visual-studio-2017#comment97675300_55482445) below, this mimicks CLI's behaviour of feeding a branch ref to `cherry-pick`, in which case it's resolved to its tip commit.)

Comment: Well.... the only thing that @RomainValeri didn't say that I think is worth mentioning is that when you cherry-pick _a branch_ (that is, the tip of a branch), in plain git (don't know how VS would behave but I think it makes sense to resemble plain old git, right?) will only cherry-pick **the tip of the branch**, not any of the previous revisions on the branch.

Comment: That was exactly the information I was looking for @eftshift0.

Answer (score -1):

Both may be used to cherry-pick but the two alternatives differ in how merge conflicts are handled. More specifically, the View History then Cherry-Pick may ask you to handle fewer merge conflicts while the "direct" Cherry-Pick may ask you to do more.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is there any documentation regarding these diferences in merging? Never heard of that.